# Express router route getting status 404 on Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, router

I'm trying to test routes done in express throught Postman but i keep getting status 404 despite i have another route that does work.

I won't post the code to the routes that do work since there's a lot of code written in here and seems unnecesary.

**App.js**

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
var bodyparser = require("body-parser")

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
var commentsRouter = require("./routes/comments")
var authRouter = require("./routes/auth")
var app = express();

var corsOption = {
  origin: true,
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ['x-auth-token']
};

// view engine setup
app.use(cors(corsOption));
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.originalUrl && req.originalUrl.split("/").pop() === "favicon.ico") {
    return res.sendStatus(204);
  }

  return next();
});

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/comments", commentsRouter)
app.use("/auth", authRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Comments route**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();


//Get comment
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    return res.status(200)
} )

/* Post new comment. */
router.post("/new", function (req, res, next) {
 return res.status(200)

});

//Update comments
router.put("/update", function (req, res, next) {
    
})

module.exports = router;
```

The index / route is working well but the /auth and /comments aren't.

I'm trying with a GET to http://localhost:3000/comments

Comment: What debugging have you done?  If you put a `console.log()` inside of your comments `router.get("/", ...)`, does it log?  Does your `app.use(function (req, res, next) { ...});` log?  This is basic debugging to see where the request is or isn't being handled.  You can also turn on Express route debugging and see exactly what Express is doing with the request.

Comment: FYI, Express route debugging for you to diagnose this yourself is described here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.status()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status) wouldn't end the response process. You need to explicit end it by chaining other methods such as `.end()` or `.send()`.

Update the GET route of `/comments` with something like this.

```js
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    return res.status(200).end();
})
```